# How we use Two 32 bit reg(32 + 32 = 64) at a time to make it able to take 64bit values? Assembly Language 8086

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

ASSEMBLY LANGUAGE 8086:

I have make a program for addition it takes two values in console and gives us result.. it can only take value under **32 bits(8 digits)** if we give higher value then it will give error of integer overflow in console winbdow..

**If i want to give more then 32bit value in input1 and input2 how will i do it?** it can be done by making array of DWORD(32bits) and put half(16 bit) half(16bit)  values

**for example:**

array1 DWORD 2 DUP(?)

array2 DWORD 2 DUP(?)

I Want add value1 to value2 by using 32bit register and give value under 64bit(equals to 16 digits).. it is Possible to use the space of 2 reg (32+32 = 64bit)?...

How we can make 2 register of 32 bit to make it 64bit i know it is possible but i dont know how to do it...because i am new in Assembly language

I am using KIP.R.IRVINE Link Libraries in Assembly Language

**how we will give 64bit value by using 2 32bit reg? or how we will enable 2 32bit reg to take 64bit value?**
i dont know how to code for it..need help in coding

here is the code for 32-bit addition:

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
    ; In above i am calling KIP.R.IRVINE Link Library for assembly language

 .data

 Addition BYTE "A: Add two Integer Numbers", 0

 inputValue1st BYTE "Input the 1st integer = ",0
 inputValue2nd BYTE "Input the 2nd integer = ",0

   outputSumMsg BYTE "The sum of the two integers is = ",0

  num1 DD ?
  num2 DD ?
  sum  DD ?

  .code

 main PROC

 ;----Displays addition Text-----

 mov edx, OFFSET Addition
 call WriteString
 call Crlf
  ;-------------------------------

 ; calling procedures here

  call InputValues
  call addValue
  call outputValue

   call Crlf

  jmp exitLabel


  main ENDP


     ; the PROCEDURES which i have made is here


  InputValues PROC
  ;----------- For 1st Value--------


   call Crlf
   mov edx,OFFSET inputValue1st ; input text1
   call WriteString

   ; here it is taking 1st value
   call ReadInt    ; read integer
   mov num1, eax   ; store the value




    ;-----------For 2nd Value----------



    mov edx,OFFSET inputValue2nd ; input text2
    call WriteString


  ; here it is taking 2nd value
  call ReadInt    ; read integer
  mov num2, eax   ; store the value

  ret
  InputValues ENDP




 ;---------Adding Sum----------------

 addValue PROC
 ; compute the sum

 mov eax, num2  ; moves num2 to eax
 add eax, num1  ; adds num2 to num1
 mov sum, eax   ; the val is stored in eax

 ret
 addValue ENDP

 ;--------For Sum Output Result----------

 outputValue PROC

 ; output result

 mov edx, OFFSET outputSumMsg ; Output text
 call WriteString


 mov eax, sum
 call WriteInt ; prints the value in eax


 ret
 outputValue ENDP


 exitLabel:
 exit


END main
```

Answer (score 1):

The 8086 (and all other processors that I've used) maintain a set of "condition codes," which includes a "carry bit" (those quoted terms are for your Googling pleasure).

When you add two unsigned 32-bit quantities, the carry bit will be set if the total exceeds 32 bits. You can add as many 32-bit (or 64-bit) quantities as you like, as long as you incorporate the carry bit from the previous addition.

Comment: It's the ADC instruction

Comment: Parsifal.if i want to give 1st value and 2nd value more than 32 bit..then it is a problem..

Comment: If you need to work with 64bit numbers on a 32bit processor and not just allow 64bit results from 32bit math then you have to write all your own math functions that eat 64bit in two 32bit registers.  In the not assembly world there are various "BigNum" libraries that do this.

Comment: @MustafaHalai - how is it a problem? Have you read about condition codes? Or looked at the documentation of the `ADC` operation? (thanks, James, it's been over 20 years since I've programmed an 8086)

Comment: For anyone who can submit a close vote: this is a duplicate of a question the OP asked two days ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16125998/can-we-use-two-32-bit-reg32-32-64-at-a-time-to-make-it-able-to-take-64bit